# Bilinear Map for Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that given map $\Bbb R[T] \to \Bbb R[T] \to \Bbb R$  is a bilinear map, additionaly symetrical and/or alternating.
I'm not completly sure if my approach was correct for $(p, q) \to p(0) + q(1)$.

**My attempt**
$f(p_1 + p_2, q) = (p_1 + p_2)(0) + q(1) = p_1(0) + p_2(0) + q(1) = f(p_1, q) + f(p_2, q)$
$f(p, q_1 + q_2) = p(0) + (q_1 + q_2)(1) = p(0) + q_1(1) + q_2(1) = f(p, q_1) + f(p, q_2)$

for the additivity.

$f(ap, q) = (ap)(0) + q(1) = ap(0) + q(1) = a(p(0) + q(1)) = af(p, q)$
$f(p, aq) = p(0) + (aq)(1) = p(0) + aq(1) = a(p(0) + q(1)) = af(p, q)$

for the homogeneity.

$f(p,q) = p(0) + q(1) \neq q(0) + p(1) = f(q,p)$

so not symetrical.

$f(p,p) = p(0) + p(1)$ is not necessearily $0$ so not alternating.

Comment: But you did not define $f$.

Comment: How a map defined on $\mathbb{R}[T]$ can be bilinear ? Do you mean a map $\mathbb{R}[T] \times \mathbb{R}[T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[T]$ ?

Comment: yes I'm sorry I edited it

Comment: The last = in the first chain of equtions can't be correct. You have (only) one $q(0)$ on the left and you should have two of them on the right.

Comment: you're right, it's just not bilinear so it would just be $\neq f(p_1, q) + f(p_2, q)$